# Microsoft Windows7 show thumbnails conflicting with open with a default program

Tags: windows, thumbnails, open-with, default-programs

I wrote a windows shell extension to show 3D files' thumbnail image, so user can search quickly. It works when users don't change default open program. However, if a user **right click** on a 3D file, then select **open with** to change default open program. It will block explorer to call my shell extension. Does anyone could help me with this?

Comment: If this helps : http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/windows-explorer-crashes-click/

Comment: I think it might be Microsoft bug. I tested on Windows 10, it's good.